# How can I loop through the $cart array, add the quantity to a running total and use a comma-delimited string to use as a query into my database?

Tags: php

I am having trouble understanding this part I have been stuck on it for a while and I think it is time to ask for some help.

What I am trying to do is use the quantity to add to a running total ($_SESSION['numItems']) and the product ID, with a comma added after it, to be appended to your $prodIDStr variable so I can use it in my table query.

This problem is just escaping me or either I am over thinking it. Either way I would appreciate some help and yes I have searched this site for another answer that would help me but with no luck.

```
foreach ($cart as $prodID => $prodQty) {
    // update the number of items in the cart
    $_SESSION['numItems'] = $prodQty;
    // comma-delimited string
    $prodIDStr = $prodIDStr . $prodID . ",";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
foreach ($cart as $prodID => $prodQty) {
    // add items to the cart (notice the '+' before '=')
    $_SESSION['numItems'] += $prodQty;
    // comma-delimited string
    $prodIDStr .= "$prodID,";
}

//remove the last comma
$prodIDStr = rtrim($prodIDStr, ',');
```

Comment: This is working and again I am over thinking the process. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your problem is that `$_SESSION['numItems']` does not contain the running total after this loop finished? That is probably because you assign `$prodQty` to `$_SESSION['numItems']` instead of adding it. Try:

```
$_SESSION['numItems'] = 0;
foreach ($cart as $prodID => $prodQty) {
    // update the number of items in the cart (note the '+')
    $_SESSION['numItems'] += $prodQty;
    // comma-delimited string
    $prodIDStr = $prodIDStr . $prodID . ",";
}
```